# How to return a double value from pthread in c++?

Tags: c++, concurrency, pthreads, pthread-join

After reading this thread: [How to return a value from thread in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251452/how-to-return-a-value-from-thread-in-c) on how to return an integer value from a pthread I tested to see if it could work for a double, but it didn't. Is there a way to return a double, long or a string from the pthread process like described in the original thread instead of returning the integer number 42?

If yes how?

And if I have a static array of 10 positions and 10 pthreads modifiying different positions each time, will I have trouble? 
AN example would be like "thread 0 modifies only array[0], thread 1 modifies only array[1] and so on".

Comment: Steve Jessop's answer is the one you want to use. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2251472/315052

Comment: Steve's answer is not the one I want. First because it still returns an int, second because it uses pthread_exit() to exit a pthread, which is a horrible, horrible solution and should be avoided. 

I have a very unique version of my code that works for integers by converting ints to uintptr_t but as far I know, there is nothing to convert from double to pointer.

Comment: Are you sure you want to go this route?  If you're on a 64 bit system then (luckily) double and void* both have 8 bytes, so you could get all the bits returned... I'll post an answer if you insist on doing this.  Probably you should just manage the data access between threads though.

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix: Are you not capable of changing the `int` to a `double`? You realize he's passing a pointer to an `int`, right? Not stuffing the int into a pointer's value. SO just pass a pointer to a double. And whatever work you need to do to not use `pthread_exit` (say, just let the function finish), do that.

Comment: Forget pthreads. Grab a modern compiler, and use C++ 11. (G++ and Clang have excellent support, and a few of the top proprietary ones have good support too.)

Comment: But if you insist on using pthreads, the standard way of doing it is to pass your thread a pointer to where you want it to store the result.

Comment: I insist on using pthreads because It is a requirement for a school project. It's that simple. As far as passing pointers, the only place where I can do that is in the pthread_create function, and I am already using it to pass a parameter.

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix: So what if you wanted to pass two parameters? You need to generalize your design. Pass a pointer to a general function-call structure. Most trivial would be to pass a pointer to a `std::function`, which you simply call. Then all this is as trivial as constructing a function to do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are just reformulations of [Steve Jessop's C solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2251472/315052) into C++. These toy examples (note the lack of error checking) use templates to make it obvious how to change the code to use some type other than `double`. For example, the `double` could be replaced with a `class` type if more than one value needed to be returned after the work is done. In practice, the base class and template would likely be removed and the `work()` method of `MyWorker` would be called directly by the invoker rather than via a virtual method.

First, using `pthread`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>

class WorkerBase {
protected: virtual ~WorkerBase () {}
public:    virtual void * work () = 0;
};

template <typename T>
struct Worker : public WorkerBase { T result; };

extern "C" void *invoke_worker (void *arg) {
    return static_cast<WorkerBase *>(arg)->work();
}

struct MyWorker : public Worker<double> {
    void * work () {
        result = 4.2;
        return 0;
    }
};

int main () {
    pthread_t t;
    MyWorker w;
    pthread_create(&t, 0, invoke_worker, &w);
    pthread_join(t, 0);
    std::cout << "result: " << w.result << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Second, using C++11 `std::thread`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

class WorkerBase {
protected: virtual ~WorkerBase () {}
public:    virtual void work () = 0;
           static void invoke (WorkerBase *w) { w->work(); }
};

template <typename T>
struct Worker : public WorkerBase { T result; };

class MyWorker : public Worker<double> {
    void work () { result = 4.2; }
};

int main () {
    MyWorker w;
    std::thread t(MyWorker::invoke, &w);
    t.join();
    std::cout << "result: " << w.result << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

You had another question in your post that I had missed:

> And if I have a static array of 10 positions and 10 pthreads modifiying different positions each time, will I have trouble?

Whether or not this gives you trouble will likely depend on the array element type and your hardware architecture. In practice, I have not observed this being a problem on x86 architectures for array elements that are aligned on machine word boundaries.

Comment: Thanks for your long answer, but passing around structures and objects is, if I am not mistaken, quite heavier than simply writing the double into a static array (a one time access to write) once the pthread has done it's job :S

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix: I modified the C++11 so that it no longer passes an object. If you object to pointers being passed, then the only solution would be a global variable.

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix: You don't even have working code and you're worried about whether or not something is "heavy"? Threads themselves are way heavier than any struct you'll pass a pointer to.

Comment: I have a working code with a static array, which is a "not so good" solution.

Answer (score 4):

The thread just has to dynamically allocate memory for the result you want it to return:

```
void *myThread(void*)
{
   double* result = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double));

   *result = 42.0;

   return result;
}
```

Whatever is supposed to collect that result dereferences the pointer returned using an appropriate cast (this is C with `void*` after all), then free the memory:

```
// calling thread (or whatever will collect the value)
void* thread_result;
int err = pthread_join( thread_handle, &thread_result);

double dbl = *(double*) thread_result;
free(thread_result);
```

As an alternative, whatever creates the thread can pass a pointer to where the thread should put it's result in the `void*` parameter to the thread (possibly as part of a struct if the thread needs more than just that bit of information).  That might allow you to avoid dynamic memory allocation if you have a reason to avoid that, but it might make ownership and lifetime of the data somewhat more complicated to manage.

Comment: I tried your solution but it doesn't compile :S <p>
pi_PThreads_2.cpp: In function ‘void* process(void*)’:
pi_PThreads_2.cpp:41:41: error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘double*’ [-fpermissive]

Comment: Just try casting the `double*` to a `void*` in that line: `return (void*)result;`

Comment: @Flame_Phoenix: sorry, my example was in C.  In a C++ source file you need to cast the return from `malloc()`: `double* result = (double*) malloc(sizeof(double));`.  I've updated the answer. If both the code that is allocating and the code freeing the object being used to return the value is C++, you should probably use `new`/`delete` instead of `malloc`/`free`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is too hard. I don't use malloc(size_t) from cstdlib, but just new.
The following example passes an argument to the thread as struct and returns another struct as well. To show it can take any variable type I also used vectors of strings...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

struct thread_data {
    int number;
    vector<string> strings;
    thread_data (){}
    thread_data(int nr) {
        number = nr;
        strings.push_back("aba\n");
    }
};

struct thread_return_data {
    int S;
    vector<string> R;
};

void *Thread (void *threadarg) {
    thread_return_data *R = new thread_return_data;
    thread_data * Q;
    Q = (thread_data *) threadarg;
    cout << Q->number << endl;
    R->S = 16; //random number
    R->R.push_back("14fjnv"); //random string
    R->R.push_back("28jfhn"); //random string
    pthread_exit(R);
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    thread_data A(4444); //initialize with random int
    thread_return_data *B; //is pointer
    pthread_t aThread; //is variable

    pthread_create(&aThread, NULL, Thread, (void *)&A);
    pthread_join(aThread, (void **)&B);

    cout << B->S << endl;
    cout << B->R[0] << endl;
    cout << B->R[1] << endl;
    cout << A.strings[0];
    delete B;

    return 0;
}
```