# Wrong return value after terminating a thread

Tags: c, pthreads, return-value

I am approaching to pthreads in C and I'm starting writing very dumb programs to get the hang of them. I tried to create a program containing two threads, they should print their name and their status should be collected as they terminate their execution. So my code is:

```
//Function declaration
void *state_your_name(char*);

//Function definition

//Passing a string as parameter for 
//outputting the name of the thread
void *state_your_name(char *name) {
    //Declaration of the variable containing the return status
    void* status;

    //Printing out the string
    printf("%s\n", name);
    //Exiting the thread and saving the return value
    pthread_exit(status);
}

int main(void) {
    pthread_t tid_1, tid_2;
    void * status;

    //Creating thread 1...
    if (pthread_create(&tid_1, NULL, state_your_name, "Thread 1")) {
        printf("Error creating thread 1");
        exit(1);
    }

    //Creating thread 2...    
    if (pthread_create(&tid_2, NULL, state_your_name, "Thread 2")) {
        printf("Error creating thread 2");
        exit(1);
    }

    //Waiting for thread 1 to terminate and 
    //collecting the return value...    
    if (pthread_join(tid_1, (void *) &status)) {
        printf("Error joining thread 1");
        exit(1);
    }
        printf("Thread 1 - Return value: %d\n", (int)status );

    //Waiting for thread 2 to terminate and 
    //collecting the return value...      
    if (pthread_join(tid_2, (void *) &status)) {
        printf("Error joining thread 2");
        exit(1);
    }
        printf("Thread 2 - Return value: %d\n", (int)status );

    return 0;
}
```

I would expect an output like this:

```
Thread 1
Thread 2
Thread 1 - Return value: 0
Thread 2 - Return value: 0
```

but my issue is the return value of `Thread 1` is `733029576`, but `Thread 2` returns `0` as predicted; it's like the status variable  is uninitialized and containing garbage. What am I missing?

Comment: D'oh, you never initialize `status`. So it's just undefined behaviour.

Comment: how do you determine your return value of thread1 has that value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you see a garbage value in the output is that the local `void *status` variable of `state_your_name` is uninitialized:

```
void *state_your_name(char *name) {
    //Declaration of the variable containing the return status
    void* status = NULL; // <<=====    Add initialization here

    //Printing out the string
    printf("%s\n", name);
    //Exiting the thread and saving the return value
    pthread_exit(status);
}
```

With this change in place, your program should produce the output that you expect.

Note that returning `status` directly from `state_your_name` is an alternative to calling `pthread_exit`: you can replace that call with `return status`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code in `state_your_name()` does not initialize the `status` that it returns, so you get indeterminate information back.  You're unlucky that you're getting zero rather than garbage.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning a pointer to `status` that is defined in the thread's stack. That memory may go away after the thread exits. You should not declare `status` inside your thread. You are better off just doing `return 0` inside `state_your_name()`.

See [How to return a value from thread in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251452/how-to-return-a-value-from-thread-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

To get a predictably different return value, try this

```
void *state_your_name(char *name) {
    //Declaration of the variable containing the return status
    void* status= (void *)(int)name[0];
    ....
```

This will return the ascii code of the first letter of the name.

Also, the implementations of pthread_join I know, take a void** as last parameter, so

```
if (pthread_join(tid_2, &status)) {
```

would be correct (your casting it `(void*)` being sort of misleading)