# C pthread, Pointer looses content

Tags: c, pointers, pthreads

I'm trying to use a returned value of a thread. For that i just found the following article: 
[How to return a value from thread in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251452/how-to-return-a-value-from-thread-in-c)

So I use the following Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void *myThread()
{
   int ret = 42;
//   printf("%d\n", ret);
   printf("%p\n",(void*)&ret);

   void * ptr = (void*)&ret;
   printf("%p\n", ptr);
   printf("%d\n", *((int *)ptr));
   return (void*) &ret;
}

int main()
{
   pthread_t tid;
   static void *status;

//   int ret = 42;
//   status = &ret;
//   printf("%d\n", *((int *)status));

   pthread_create(&tid, NULL, myThread, NULL);
   pthread_join(tid, &status);

   printf("%p\n",((int *)status));  
   printf("%d\n", *((int *)status));
   return 0;
}
```

The outputs are: 
0x7f7ead136f04,
0x7f7ead136f04,
**42**,
0x7f7ead136f04,
**0**

Why is the last value not 42?

Same Problem here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

     void* aufgabe_drei_thread() {
         int i = 5;
         return &i; 
     }

int main(int argc, char** argv) { 
    int* ptr_wert_aus_drei;
    pthread_t thread_three_id;
    pthread_create(&thread_three_id, NULL, aufgabe_drei_thread, NULL);
    pthread_join (thread_three_id, &ptr_wert_aus_drei);
    printf("Der Wert aus Thread 3 ist: %d\n", *((int *)ptr_wert_aus_drei));

     return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Output is: Der Wert aus Thread 3 ist: 32508
 and not 5.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You can't return a pointer to a local variable. Local variables are destroyed when the function is over.

Answer (score 2):

Allocate on the heap to hang onto the value, or pass a pointer to store it.

This:

```
void *myThread(void *opaque)
{
   int *ret = malloc(sizeof(int));
   *ret = 42;
//   printf("%d\n", *ret);
   printf("%p\n",(void*) ret);

   void * ptr = (void*) ret;
   printf("%p\n", ptr);
   printf("%d\n", *((int *)ptr));
   return (void*) ret;
}
```

Or this:

```
void *myThread(void *opaque)
{
   int *ret = (int *) opaque;
   *ret = 42;
//   printf("%d\n", *ret);
   printf("%p\n",(void*) ret);

   void * ptr = (void*) ret;
   printf("%p\n", ptr);
   printf("%d\n", *((int *)ptr));
   return NULL;
}
```

While passing the variable like this:

```
pthread_create(&tid, NULL, myThread, &status);
pthread_join(tid, NULL);
```

Answer (score 2):

Declare `i` as global because inside `aufgabe_drei_thread()` `i` will be destroyed when the function exits.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int i = 0;

void* aufgabe_drei_thread() { 
    i = 42;       
    return &i; 
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) { 
    int* ptr_wert_aus_drei;
    pthread_t thread_three_id;
    pthread_create(&thread_three_id, NULL, aufgabe_drei_thread, NULL);
    pthread_join (thread_three_id, &ptr_wert_aus_drei);
    printf("Der Wert aus Thread 3 ist: %d\n", *((int *)ptr_wert_aus_drei));

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

or

```
void* aufgabe_drei_thread() {       
    return (void*) 42; 
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) { 
    int* ptr_wert_aus_drei;
    pthread_t thread_three_id;
    pthread_create(&thread_three_id, NULL, aufgabe_drei_thread, NULL);
    pthread_join (thread_three_id, &ptr_wert_aus_drei);
    printf("Der Wert aus Thread 3 ist: %d\n", *((int *)ptr_wert_aus_drei));

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```