# c++ how to fix the segmentation fault 11 in this code

Tags: c++

I have a signal 11; i.e. *segfault*. I know where it occurs (see code), but do not know how to correct it.

```
int *totalThreadNumProduced; //array
int *totalThreadNumConsumed; //array
int *tempStats; //array
for(int i=0; i < global_args.numProducers; i++)
{  
    tempStats = (int*) pthread_join( tidP[i], NULL );
    simulationStats.totalThreadNumProduced[i] = tempStats[0]; //where the segmentation fault 11 is
    simulationStats.numTimesBufferFull += tempStats[1];

}
```

Comment: Have you allocated the memory for those three array?

Comment: @ChenOT pointers.

Comment: `pthread_join( tidP[i], NULL );` will return `0` on success, or an error code on failure. None of those will most likely be a valid pointer value. Also as this is obviously not your real code, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: ibm has a sample code of (what i think) you are trying to do: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.bpxbd00/ptjoin.htm

Answer (score 0):

```
tempStats = (int*) pthread_join( tidP[i], NULL );
```

`tempStats` is an array of integers, judging from the following line:

```
simulationStats.totalThreadNumProduced[i] = tempStats[0];
```

the segfault is either due to memory not being allocated for `totalThreadNumProduced`, or `tempStats`.

Furthermore, your usage for [`pthread_join`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html) is likely incorrect; it simply returns whether the call was successful or not. If you wanting the return value of a completed thread function, consider using the 2nd *status* parameter of `pthread_join` as show [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251452/how-to-return-a-value-from-thread-in-c).

Comment: A pointer is a pointer. An array is an array. A pointer is no array. An array is no pointer.

Comment: The first element of a 1D array can be accessed using array_name or array_name[0]; i.e. an array is a pointer to a sequence of identical data-types.  Usually, people use the square bracket notation to access 'elements' but that can also be done use pointer arithmetic. *(array_name+5) is that same as array_name[5].

Comment: That an array when used as a value and not as operand of the `sizeof` or address-of operator is \*converted\* to a pointer to its first element is not the same as it *being* a pointer. – *an array is a pointer to a sequence of identical data-types.* – No, an array is not a pointer. And `int *tempStats;` is certainly no array.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3959705/arrays-are-pointers

Okay, thanks for the enlightenment; I think I understand what you are saying now. With that said, what do we call a pointer that has been malloc'd *m* items? That is what seems to be the problem - OP is attempting to use a pointer as an array without allocating memory to the pointer.